# I run into this PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix with base and other named enviornment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

in my base virtual environment conda update conda works but conda update anaconda doesn't work

```
(base) heang:~$ conda update anaconda
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: /home/heang/anaconda3
package name: anaconda
```

while other virtual environment named py3_torch  conda update conda doesn't work but conda update anaconda doesn't work

```
(py3_torch) heang:~$ conda update conda
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: /home/heang/anaconda3/envs/py3_torch
package name: conda
```

and when I deactivate environment and run conda update conda then it runs but when I run conda update anaconda, again the same error

```
heang:~$ conda update anaconda
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: /home/heang/anaconda3
package name: anaconda
```

I want to know whats happening ? I wanted to update spyder but that got me into this pickle. Thank you

What does conda list -n base conda show?

```
(base) heang:~$ conda list -n base conda
# packages in environment at /home/heang/anaconda3:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda-client           1.11.1          py310h06a4308_0  
anaconda-navigator        2.4.0           py310h06a4308_0 
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py310h06a4308_0 
conda                     23.5.1          py310h06a4308_0 
conda-build               3.23.3          py310h06a4308_0  
conda-content-trust       0.1.3           py310h06a4308_0  
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0 
conda-package-handling    2.0.2           py310h06a4308_0
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0           py310h06a4308_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.41          py310h06a4308_0
conda-token               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
```

and when I do

```
conda list -n py3_torch conda
```

it shows

```
# packages in environment at /home/heang/anaconda3/envs/py3_torch:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2023.07                 py310_0 
anaconda                  custom                  py310_2
```

and I mostly work in py3_torch environment.

Comment: Did you uninstall the `anaconda` from the Anaconda **base** environment? What does `conda list -n base conda` show? (Please add output to question, not as a comment)

Comment: No I haven't uninstalled anaconda from base environment

Comment: you speak of `conda activate conda/anaconda` in the text, while in your code you always have `update`. Which do you mean. Is that the complete list for the base env that you have shown?

Comment: Sorry I meant {conda update conda/anaconda } , no it shows only conda pkgs

Comment: Well you don’t have `anaconda` package installed (navigator, client, and project are specific utilities, not the Anaconda distribution). And the commands shown to update `conda` are both run without **base** activated (where `conda` is installed). For more consistency I recommend always specifying the target environment: `conda update -n base conda anaconda-navigator`

Comment: then how do I install anaconda package ? as I want to update spyder and it (spyder) recommended first conda update anaconda and then update spyder. Also, i've uploaded what I see when py3_torch environment is activated. Thanks